Who is "Einnehmer"?
Note: The original question asked for "Zinnehmer", which is a misreading.
In Austrian government books from "Schematismus des Königreiches Galizien und Lodomerien" series from ca. 1825 I came across the term "Provis. Zinnehmer", which described some sort of customs official:

But what was the full name of that position and what was the responsibility of such a man?
When I've Googled for "Zinnehmer" I got results related almost entirely to different Schematismus, which was not very helpful...

This is surely an "E", so the word is "Einnehmer". Just look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur#Typeface_samples, a "Z" looks nothing like that. As for "provis", the two stems duden knows starting with it are either "Provision" (commision) and "provisorisch" (provisionally). (Answers should not be comments, and I hope we get a "proper" answer explaining what an "Einnehmer" and "Schrankenzieher" at a "Weg- und Brückenmauthamt" were.)

The original question asked for "Zinnehmer", which is a misreading. If the question is therefore obsolet, please delete it yourself. If it is adaptable to the correct reading, please correct it in that regard.

@Dodezv: Thank you for your answer! I feel embarrassed that I forgot to check such an obvious thing as typeface :(

The word »einnehmen« is a Verb. It means to earn, to make (money):

Wie lief das Geschäft heute?
Ganz gut, ich habe fast 10.000 Euro eingenommen, und rechne damit, dass ich morgen 15.000 Euro einnnehmen werde.
How did business go today?
Quite well, I made almost 10,000 euros and I expect to make 15,000 euros tomorrow.

This verb describes exactly what an official does whose job it is to collect tolls and taxes. And if you convert this verb into a noun (which is called nominalization), you get: Einnehmer. So it's the name for a profession. You could translate it as cashier. See also: https://www.geschichtewiki.wien.gv.at/Einnehmer
Here is the full text of the section shown in the original post:

K. K. Weg- und Brückenmauthamt
Makow.
Provis. Einnehmer. Hr. Michael Ludwig.
1 Schrankenzieher.
Jordanow.
Verpachtet.
Mszana dolna.
Provis. Einnehmer. Hr. Joseph Loreth.
1 Schrankenzieher.
Dobra.
Provis. Einnehmer. Hr. Kaspar Appel.
1 Schrankenzieher.
Limanow.
Provis. Einnehmer. Hr. Joh. Gräfner.
1 Schrankenzieher.


»K. K.« is the abbreviation for »kaiserlich-königlich« ("imperial-royal", i.e. belonging to the emperor and king)
»Weg- und Brückenmautamt« means road and bridge toll office
»provis.« is the abbreviation for »provisorisch« (provisional)
»verpachtet« means leased.
A »Schrankenzieher« is a barrier puller.
»Hr.« is the abbreviation for »Herr« (mister)
All other words are proper names.


Thank you for your detailed answer! I feel embarassed that I forgot to check such an obvious thing as typeface :(
But still it was very helful for me that you explained also other abbreviations, especially "provis." which does not occur so often in documents from k.k-Era which I've come across so far...
